# How do I prevent code repeat between rvalue and lvalue member functions?

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics, rvalue-reference, move-constructor

For the program code below, I have to write the the same code inside the pair of member functions which receiving rvalue and lvalue references.

My aim is to use only one from the pair (e.g.; only use the rvalue accepting ones), and the others. I read the reference of `std::forward`, as far as I understood, it looks like it is for this purpose. But, when I delete the lvalue reference taking ones, I get the following compiler error.

> 'TestClass::TestClass(const TestClass &)': cannot convert argument 1 from 'std::wstring' to 'std::wstring &&'

How do I prevent this code duplication?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

class TestClass
{
    public:
        TestClass(const std::wstring    &  Text)
            : Text(Text)
        {
            std::wcout << L"LValue Constructor : " << Text << std::endl;
            /*Some code here...*/
        }
        TestClass(      std::wstring    && Text)
            : Text(std::forward<std::wstring>(Text))
        {
            std::wcout << L"RValue Constructor : " << this->Text << std::endl;
            /*Same code here...*/
        }
        TestClass(const TestClass       &  Another)
            : Text(Another.Text)
        {
            std::wcout << L"Copy   Constructor : " << Text << std::endl;
            /*Some code here...*/
        }
        TestClass(      TestClass       && Another)
            : Text(std::forward<std::wstring>(Another.Text))
        {
            std::wcout << L"Move   Constructor : " << Text << std::endl;
            /*Same code here...*/
        }

    private:
        std::wstring Text;
};

int wmain(int argc, wchar_t *argv[], wchar_t *envp[])
{
    std::wstring Argument(L"Testing Copy");
    TestClass Class1Copy(Argument);
    TestClass Class1Move(L"Testing Move");
    TestClass Class2Copy(Class1Copy);
    TestClass Class2Move(std::move(Class1Move));

    _wsystem(L"pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
LValue Constructor : Testing Copy  
RValue Constructor : Testing Move  
Copy   Constructor : Testing Copy  
Move   Constructor : Testing Move  
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Comment: `Text(std::forward<std::wstring>(Text))` should really be `Text(std::move(Text))`. Same in the other places you have used `forward` instead of `move`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If move construction is expected to be extremely cheap, you can take by value and move-from the value.  This does exactly 1 more move than a pair of copy and move overloads.

If you want optimal efficiency, and/or if move construction is *cheaper* but not *cheap* enough to neglect, you can forward:

```
template<class T>
std::decay_t<T> copy(T&& t) {
  return std::forward<T>(t);
}
class TestClass {
public:
  TestClass(std::wstring const&  Text)
    TestClass( copy(Text) )
  {}
  TestClass(TestClass const& o)
    : TestClass( o.Text )
  {}
  TestClass(TestClass&& o)
    : TestClass( std::move(o).Text ) // pattern does the right thing more often than `std::move(o.Text)` does.
  {}
  // only "real" ctor:
  TestClass( std::wstring&& Text)
    : Text(std::forward<std::wstring>(Text))
  {
    std::wcout << L"RValue Constructor : " << this->Text << std::endl;
    /*Code here...*/
  }
// ...
```

now everything forwards down to the one constructor.

You can even mix the two techniques: use by-value for `std::wstring` (as we know that is cheap-to-move) and do forwarding stuff for the `TestClass` code (or anything less likely to be stable).

Answer (score 2):

You can take by value and then `move`. Then you only need `N` overloads, not `2N`:

```
TestClass(std::wstring Text)
    : Text(std::move(Text))
{
}
```

You can avoid the copy constructor and move constructor duplication by writing nothing at all; the compiler will generate them by default in this case.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that since the function's signatures determine when and where they are used.  It's like a `copy constructor` and an `assignment operator`.  They do *somewhat* similar things but the compiler calls the appropriate one basee on context.

If you want to avoid reusing code, just factor out the commonality into a separate function.